# Glassfish 3 cannot consume non secure web service

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish, jax-ws, glassfish-3

I would like to consume not SSL (over http) web service from an application deployed on Glassfish 3 server.
The web service is secured with basic authentication.
I use JAX-WS client and I generated the client with wsimport tool.
When the web service is invoked I get an error:

> XWSSecurityRuntimeException WSS1601: Security Requirements not met - Transport binding configured in policy but incoming message was not SSL enabled
>                       at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.policy.verifier.MessagePolicyVerifier.verifyPolicy(MessagePolicyVerifier.java:125)

Could anybody point me how to configure Glassfish (or JAX-WS) to allow me to consume this kind of service?